# If an object suspended by a string is immersed in a liquid, will its weight contribute to the pressure at the bottom of the container?

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics, buoyancy, weight

We have a metal sphere completely immersed in a liquid of density A by means of a string.

Since the sphere is exerted by the buoyant force due to the liquid the sphere must also exert an equal and opposite force on the liquid. So wouldn't that contribute to the pressure at the bottom ?

(Assuming no atmospheric pressure)

[image: The diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the set-up is in equilibrium, and that the atmospheric pressure is zero, the tension in the string would balance the apparent weight of the sphere (the apparent weight being mg-buoyant force).

The pressure at the bottom of the vessel will be equal to the weight of the substance above it divided by the area of the vessel.

Since the apparent weight of the sphere is being balanced by the tension in the string, it wont contribute to the pressure at the bottom of the vessel.